# Is there a closed-form expression for the $z$-transform of $sinc[k]$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, power-series, z-transform

Eventually, it is just this question:

Define $\text{sinc}(x):=\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$ if $x\neq0$

$\text{sinc}(x):=a$ if $x=0$

How to simplify this series:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\text{sinc}(k)z^{-k}$$
Is there any closed form for it?

Comment: When one of your terms has a zero denominator, we can stop trying to evaluate it.  So let's say we omit that term.

Comment: @Xavier Yang Are you sure that $k$ starts from $-\infty$? Moreover, what did you find for the convergence?

Comment: Yes. But well, here we actually sum up the sinc function.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a$ is real, and is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.  Then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(ak)}{k} z^{-k}
$$
diverges if $|z| < 1$, converges absolutely if $|z|>1$, and converges conditionally (and not absolutely) for $z$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$.  [Divergence is because the term does not go to zero.]

On the other hand,
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{\sin(ak)}{k} z^{-k}
$$
converges absolutely if $|z|<1$, diverges if $|z|>1$, and converges conditionally (and not absolutely) for for $z$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$.

So, the series
$$
\sum_{k \ne 0} \frac{\sin(ak)}{k} z^{-k}
$$
diverges for all $z$ except the unit circle $|z|=1$.  On the unit circle, the series does not converge absolutely, so rearrangement of the series matters.  For such $z$, the principal value in the sense
$$
a+\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=-N}^{-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\right) \frac{\sin(ak)}{k} z^{-k}
$$
exists.

For example, if $z=1$ Maple gives me the following stairstep function:

[image: stairstep]

**added**
Maple says the closed form is
$$
a-\arctan \left( {\frac {\sin \left( a \right) }{\cos \left( a
 \right) -z}} \right) +\arctan \left( {\frac {z\sin \left( a \right) 
}{1-z\cos \left( a \right) }} \right) 
$$

Comment: The question of closed-form is still... open. There is an answer (by Robert Israel) there: (https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/12273-1.php)

Comment: do you know the derivation of it, thx!

Comment: @XavierYang For which derivation are you interested in?

Comment: Look at the forum answer I have indicated where you will find the proof for formula $ 1 + (-ln(1 - exp(ia)/z) + ln(1 - exp(-ia)/z))/(2 i a)$. Is it the same as the formula given by @GEdgar, I don't know.